# Extracting data from the latest date given in each month

Tags: sql, sql-server

My goal is to extract from my database all of the records that fall NOT on the end of the month, but on the last date that exists in each month within the data (although some of these may so happen to be the end of the month).

Currently, just to simply get the latest dates for each month, using the following code alone takes 26 minutes:

```
SELECT Max(DATE)
FROM Accounts
GROUP BY Year(Date), Month(Date);
```

The point being that for the 16M rows that we have, running this as a subquery for the FROM statement within a temp_table is just not the speed improvement we were looking for (currently it takes about 40 minutes to read in the whole table anyway).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use window functions:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             rank() over (partition by year(date), month(date)
                          order by day(date) desc) as seqnum
      from accounts a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  the use of `rank()` (or equivalently `dense_rank()`) will return all rows for the last day of each month.  If you only wanted one record, you can use `row_number()` instead.